# What are docker apps and why would I choose them over normal containers or docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I just found out that docker is launching a new feature called ["Docker App"](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-app) and is defined as:

> Docker App is a way to define, package, execute, and manage distributed applications and coupled services as a single, immutable object. Making complex multi-service applications as easy to build, share and run as single containers

Looking more into it, it seems like it is another way to [package your application with the tools required to run/provision it incorporated based on CNAB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26e5-UK4YRA) (YouTube link with Microsoft explanation on what CNAB is).

While reading some articles online I found out that is used mostly to provision a collection of Docker images containing everything required to perform an installation against a remote resource.
But to my knowledge we have quite some tools that do exactly that (Terraform, Ansible and Puppet to name some)

And while I know this is still in experimental phase, I fail to understand when would I choose Docker App over docker-compose or already existing provisioning tools?

Comment: The correct comparison should be made with Kubernetes, as docker-compose is little more than a development tool.

Comment: Also, you would never choose Docker App over any other solution. It's another misstep by a company that is characterised by its missteps. Another product searching for a use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Docker Compose with a separate file for configuration and a third file for metadata. You can add a Docker App to a registry. You would choose it over Docker Compose because the configuration file would be useful and so would the ability to push/pull the app as a unit to/from a registry.

It is a packaging tool. It's aiming to apply the same benefits that Docker has for monolithic applications to multi-service applications. Simplicity is an objective. It looks like it will be easy to get to grips with. This will mean many people will choose it over Kubernetes. Kubernetes has a reputation as being hard and you can't just dive in without familiarising yourself with its concepts and terminology.